# Bounty on someone else's question but original asker doesn't respond to new answers

Tags: discussion, bounties, specific-question

I have put a bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796109/python-how-to-relaunch-the-application-on-the-fly-while-the-application-having), and a bunch of useful answers have popped up since I added the bounty.

Unfortunately the original asker doesn't seem to be checking out the new answers, and the nature of the question is such that the original asker has to try out the answers to see which one (if any) works. I can't try it out myself because you need more code than is given in the question.

If OP doesn't show back up, who should I award the bounty to? What are we supposed to do in this situation?

Comment: Was this bounty more charitable than anything? It sounds as if you put a bounty on something to help someone else. Or, do you have a technical interest in the question as well? In other words, can you explain what motivated you to post the bounty to begin with?

Comment: @TinyTimPost It was partially charitable, but I've had very similar problems in the past and anticipate having more like them in the future. My similar past issues have all gotten resolved, but I wanted to find out how this was different in case I (or someone else searching SO) run into it in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not be relying on the OP's input whatsoever in this situation. It is *your* bounty which you placed on the question because *you* (supposedly) wanted an answer to the question that was not provided. So, the decision falls into your hands. Figure out which answer helped *you* most - your bounty is basically like having your own checkmark. It's what helped you most, not what helped the OP. If none of the answers helped you at all, then by all means don't award the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

If it is something you can try out and verify, go ahead and check those answers and award bounty to the one which deserves it. Or else wait for the OP to verify it. There is still an option as, if some answer gets 2 or more upvotes(the one with maximum upvotes), half of the bounty will be automatically awarded to that answer at the end of the bounty period. That should reward the person who comes up with the right answer in this case. I doubt there is anything else you can do on this regard. If it is your bounty, it is expected that the answer should be useful for 'you' in someways. So you should be able to check that aspect of the answer.

Comment: I can't try it out, because you need more code than is given in the question. The current top answer was given before the bounty was started; will half still go to the top answer?

Comment: No, it wont. The answer should be posted once the bounty has started. You can check this for more details http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work. Basically the assumption is that you wouldn't have put a bounty on that if the previous answer was useful. Hence the system wont consider that.